# how to use the 'natbib' package to create citation call-outs?

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I want to change the style of my current referencing and I found `natbib` but I am having trouble with it. The style I am using now is: 
[image]

I want to eliminate the square brackets and leave the year between `()`. Like this: `Jones et al. (1990)`.

This is a short list of the code I am using:

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany, letterpaper, pagesize]{scrbook}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{cite} %para citar dentro del texto

\begin{document}

% The stuff of my work....

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{Bibli}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't load the `cite` package with `natbib`; load the `round` option with `natbib`: `\usepackage[round]{natbib}` (even though that's already the default...) and use `\citet{<key>}` in your main document

Comment: Damn, I did not see, you did recommend `\citet`, before answering myself. I suggest you promote your comment to an answer...

Comment: @OlegLobachev It's cool :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`natbib`'s `\citet` function produces "Jones et al. [2001]". The kind of parenthesis and brackets, the symbol between name and year (Jones et al., 2001), etc. are configureable in setup options of `natbib`.

People often recommend `biblatex`, if you start from scratch. I found it quite hard to use it to mimic the older styles 100% exact, but ymmv.

Comment: You should also advise the OP to specify the option `round` while loading `natbib`. That way, round parentheses rather than square brackets will be used to enclose the citation call-out.